# Returning a CString will call the destructor?

Tags: c++, cstring

What happenes if i return a CString from a method? will it call the destructor of the CString?

```
CString f(){

CString s = g();

return s;

}

const char* g(){ return new char[5]; }
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not necessarily.

If your compiler implements Return Value Optimization (RVO) then it can set up the call to `f()` such that `s` is constructed where the caller would store the return value, and therefore it can elide the calls to the `CString` copy constructor and destructor. This optimization is one of the few exceptions permitted by the C++ standard to the as-if optimization rule.

If you are compiling with all optimizations disabled, you would likely see one or more calls to the `CString` copy constructor and destructor in processing the call to `f()`.

Comment: This changes the semantics of the language.  If you have declared a destructor for an object and it ceases to exist (as the function it belongs to finishes) an automatic call to the destructor must be made.  I don't know if you are referring to the C++11 or some other later, but in previous calling the destructor is forced.

Comment: @LuisColorado Let's say that the call here is `CString x = f();` As I mention in my answer, with RVO the returned object (`s` in this example) will be constructed *at the same location* as `x`. So the object does not "cease to exist" at all, it's simply constructed *where it was going to be anyway*, which means that the return value isn't copied at all. If the compiler does not implement RVO then yes, the returned object will be copied into a temporary and then destructed, then the temporary in turn would be copied into `x` and destructed. The standard permits these two copies to be omitted.

Comment: @LuisColorado [This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) does a pretty good job at explaining what is going on. See also [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e96d71c25a791c89) I just wrote that shows the difference when copy elision is turned off -- you see the behavior that you and OP are expecting. Both behaviors in this example are allowed by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will call the destructor of any object that ceases to exist when you finish function execution.  As `s` is declared local to the function `f()`, al local objects (as `s` is) will cease to exist and as such, the compiler will call their destructor.